# How Do Portlet-Bridge, Richfaces and ajax4jsf work together?

Tags: richfaces, jsf-2, liferay

I am trying to get Liferay 6.0, JBoss portlet bridge 2.0 and Richfaces 4.0.0 working together by using the configuration as stated in [JBoss Forum](http://community.jboss.org/message/2245) and [the portlet bridge documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/portletbridge/docs/2.0.0.FINAL/en/html_single/index.html). My goal is to use JSF 2.0 when implementing protlets.

I use maven for building and deploying the portlet in Liferay and included the Richfaces dependancy like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2-FCS</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.portletbridge</groupId>
  <artifactId>portletbridge-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.CR1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.portletbridge</groupId>
  <artifactId>portletbridge-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.CR1</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.20100826-M2</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.15.B1</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I use this configuration I get the following error:

```
 SEVERE: Exception starting filter ajax4jsf
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ajax4jsf.Filter
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:269)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3838)
[...]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

So I looked again at the forum and found [this post](http://community.jboss.org/message/557887), which says in my opinion that ajax4jsf does not need any configuration in web.xml and portlet.xml anymore. So I threw it out and got the following error:

```
[TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader@1738d88] error can't determine annotations of missing type org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxViewRootRenderer
```

Now I am confused: Do I have to configure ajax4jsf in web.xml? Why isn't it found by Liferay? And what is this module good for anyway, JSF 2.0 implementation or richfaces proprietary functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The only version of JBoss Portlet Bridge that supports JSF 2 is in alpha
[here](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/portletbridge/portletbridge-impl/3.0.0.ALPHA/portletbridge-impl-3.0.0.ALPHA.jar). You can drop the jar in your lib folder with the 2.0.0.FINAL api jar. Also, there are maven based examples in svn that have a Liferay profile "mvn package -Pliferay".

Comment: No success, I still get the same error. Do you know, if I have to specify  the ajax4jsf filter in web.xml or if I can leave it out?

Comment: Also, when I try to compile the project via svn and maven I get the error: "[INFO] The specified web.xml file '/home/bme/Workspace/jboss-portletbridge-3.0.0.ALPHA/examples/jsf2portlet/src/main/liferay/liferay-web.xml' does not exist". Is the web.xml obsolete?